# Why can I no longer ask questions when all I did was ask some simple questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, post-ban

I have asked the three questions below, one of which I deleted myself. How can Stack Overflow  block me from asking further questions? It seems Stack Overflow is not for beginners, but just for people with years of experience.

Could anyone tell me what the problem is with my questions and how I can improve them?

- [Add values to dropdown list programatically at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731161/add-values-to-dropdown-list-programatically-at-run-time)
- [Validate Indian Phone number with optional +91 or 0 preceeding 10 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758315/validate-indian-phone-number-with-optional-91-or-0-preceeding-10-digits)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758496/adding-barcode-reader-ability-in-c-sharp-application (deleted by myself)

Comment: is your question deleted   which is negatively voted ?

Comment: You forgot to mention the one that was deleted by yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758496/adding-barcode-reader-ability-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: `Seems stack overflow is not for beginners, but just for people with years of experience` - please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152067/147640.

Comment: yeah, so what, but point is, I was given -4 for 2nd question . I fail to understand why

Comment: @Oded if there is only one deleted question then ... isnt question ban is too early  i mean just after 4 down-votes ?

Comment: Let me add third question also

Comment: To be honest, asking a simple question on my first or 2nd day , and me being doing programming since 1 month. So many experianced users down voted my question instead of helping me. So I deleted that one question.

Comment: Especially with regard to your deleted question you might want to read [an answer I've just given](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182007/how-often-should-i-ask-a-question-on-stack-overflow/182010#182010) on when and how often you should ask questions on Stack Overflow. Doing your own research is very important. The "I have no clue where to start" question is not really a good fit for SO.

Comment: Duplicate ?? If I am facing this problem, obviously  I will post it here, in hope stack overflow will help

Comment: @Bart So, in nutshell, deleting one question is all it takes for asking any further questions.

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody duplicate means someone else already faced this problem and for help you can see that post ... and its helpful isnt it ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя  I just posted this question again myself just to highlight this issue . Don't you feel experienced persons sometimes instead of helping with simple question just downvote :(

Comment: We're supposed to help here, why is this question being downvoted as well?

Comment: And most importantly i fail to understand, when i deleted that question, stack overflow awarded me with peer pressure badge. It just seems contradictory, first awarding badge then banning me from asking any further questions when all I had asked was 3 questions

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody From experience I fear that with the three questions and the downvotes you say you received, we don't actually have the full history of your account. But only a moderator can confirm that. That said, deleting your downvoted questions is a sure sign for the system that you're posting bad content. At some point it will stop you from doing so. It's however the overall picture that needs to be bad. Not a single post.

Comment: @Bart I have nothing to hide, if it can help, I can provide even my account ID and password for the same as it wont affect me in any way

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody No need for that. Let moderators handle the behind-the-scenes. Assuming your information is complete, I'm slightly surprised for it to kick in relatively early. And perhaps our experience with other users ruins things a bit for you here. In any case, your questions are not great. And the one you deleted was a particularly bad fit.

Comment: @Bart Yeah you right, still don't you think from programmer with month experience , you can't expect lot that early

Comment: The questions you have are fair. Even the one you ultimately deleted is a fair question to have at the start. No problem there. That doesn't make them a good fit for Stack Overflow however. Stack Overflow has a fairly narrow scope. Anything outside that tends to get "cleaned up" by the community fairly rapidly. That's what makes the site as good as it is, but also raises the entry level somewhat.

Comment: I guess time is also a factor. 5 downvotes on different questions in a short while has more weight than 5 downvotes spread over long period of time. Anyway what's done is done, the ban is 100% automatic. Read the linked faq question, everything you can do to lift the ban is already described in there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are no longer question banned. You asked a regex question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758315/validate-indian-phone-number-with-optional-91-or-0-preceeding-10-digits), which received a few down votes but wasn't what I'd call a horrible question. Then you asked this [extremely vague question about a bar code scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758496/adding-barcode-reader-ability-in-c-sharp-application), which you deleted after it received some down votes. Deleted questions are considered when the block is applied, and can actually count against you more. Thus, you weren't able to ask questions.

Up votes on your remaining posts automatically lifted the block, but do take care - you're right at that edge. If you have a question that is *narrowly* scoped, like:

> I tried the following code to read input from a bar code reader but I get the following error:

.. we can probably help you. In the question you asked, you had no implementation yet - 'where do I start' is a question you need to answer first - we're here when you have some code, or a much more narrow question to ask. The question was simply too broad. Remember to read our guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take a look at some existing up voted questions on the site to get a better idea of what would be a good fit.

Good luck, and enjoy.

Comment: So those three questions are all there is to the user's history? Did things get tightened up recently? Because that seems awfully quick for the ban to kick in, even if not completely unjustified.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate, I will try utmost to ask question of optimum quality

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody Before you ask your next question, have a read through this excellent bit of advice: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Bart . You really helped me here alot

Comment: @Bart He was an edge case really, it was just the difference of one up vote. He had _just_ enough activity for the algorithm to run, and most of what was there counted against him (deleting rather than improving is one of the things we try to heavily discourage). Most that hit this early on have had a few 'whoppers' which haven't been deleted.

Comment: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

Comment: This is what I get now, even before I can post any other question , I am banned again, coz some users seems to be having really high ego i think, coz down votes again on old questions :(

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody Instead of going the "ego" route, actually improve your content. That's the way out, as indicated in the post you get to when following the link.

Comment: @TimPost I see. Fair enough. I guess that indeed because of the usual suspects that pop up here, I had assumed the algorithm to be more relaxed than it actually is.

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody You undeleted the third question without improving it, and everyone on Meta is currently looking at your posts as you brought this issue here - despite being given basically the same advice in the link the system provided you. You were clear of the ban when I posted this, I suggest improving the question you undeleted (after the ban had been lifted), that should get you the votes you need to work out of this.

Comment: @Bart I received down votes on regular expression for indian phone number. When 90% of the answer i had given there, all i needed was little help. How to ask that question any other way :(

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody Everyone looking at your question here is now looking at everything you have ever written on the site and voting on it in one direction or another. I suggest you improve the question you undeleted _very_ soon, and just wait to see what happens. We provide the comprehensive summary the system gave you a link to _precisely so individual question blocks aren't hashed out here_, for _precisely this reason_.

Comment: I can't improve that question for simple reason I don't need answer of that anymore. Still I am trying to change that question altogether

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody The block has been lifted (again) due to voting activity, and some editorial help from users that have read your post. I'd .. not do anything .. for the next few hours and let things settle down, after that you should be able to ask questions. The edits folks have made to your posts are good - you can study the changes to better sharpen your future questions, which should result in a consistently good experience for you here.

Comment: Thanks @TimPost , I really appreciate your help

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody Normally, editing a question to completely change its scope is frowned upon, but I don't see what else you could have done with it. It was previously deleted, had no answers and no hope of improvement as it stood, so it looks like what you did (asking an actual question in its place) will work. If there's controversy over that, feel free to link to this comment thread.

Comment: Yes I will @TimPost, although that question has been closed, but that was the question I wanted to ask in first place today. Still I am bit confused, can I ask that question again, so that I get answer or it will be considered as duplicate

Comment: That question is no longer closed, thanks to all, stay blessed all.